# Cannot upload inside a shared Sharepoint drive, got 'Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header'

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to upload a simple text  document to a sharepoint shared document folder. My account do have write access within this folder.

To acheive that, I'm using the [Microsoft Graph API v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request-to-upload-a-new-file).

According to the doc, I'm making the following request: `PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drive/items/Shared%20Documents/{name_of_folder}:/text.txt:/content`

I've set `Content-Type` to be `text/plain` and my body is just 'text'.

The Microsoft Graph API send me the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-08-23T08:10:44",
            "request-id": "51fcdf1f-d7d0-4585-b712-ddd0197e046e", 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I've managed to upload a document using `PUT /me/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content`

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Could you share request id and timestamp from the inner error. Also clarify if you are accessing the folder using the shared files remarks in [List items shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#remarks)

Comment: @Danstan I've updated the post with request-id and date. I do not have access to the folder requesting the 'List items shared' API... (I do have access to it using the Sharepoint website)

Comment: If you don't have access to the shared item using the shared with me API, the PUT will not work because it means you don't have write access. Let me check it out further and get back with my findings.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I'm able to upload files inside the folder using the Sharepoint website

Comment: Okay.  I will try to recreate your scenario. Is the folder shared from a another user or from a document library?

Comment: From a document library of a site I'm not part of

Comment: It seems the error is misleading and may not tell what really happened. Is the file shared to a work account or a personal account? How have you acquired the access token and what scopes are added to it? Also you may want to try this in Graph explorer by logging in with the account to which folder was shared.